# Bootstrap Div Colors only one Row in form

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I do have the following code block. Except for the custom sheets, bootstrap was used.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .filter-box-margins {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
  
  .filer-box-height {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .filter-box-background {
    background-color: rgb(199, 214, 243);
    background-size: 100%;
  }
</style>
<div class="row filter-box-background filter-box-height filter-box-margins">
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-body col-md-12 ">
    <form class="form-control-sm">

      <div class="form-row">

      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputState">Make</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control input-sm">
            <option selected>Any</option>
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputPassword4">Keywords</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input sm" id="search" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, color is only applied as shown in the below image.

[image]

Any reason why the color is only applied to the first `form-row`

Comment: When I run your code it is showing the background colour correctly

Comment: If possible, could you please upload the full example somewhere on stackblitz and share the URL. When I ran the code it was showing exactly as its running in the given code snippet. Please check if you have some internal styling getting conflicted. Such as sudo classes :first :first-child, :nth-child(1).